# Error page redirection not working properly on angular lazy loading

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-routing, angular-router

I am stuck in a situation and need some help from experts. My application is made on top of lazy-loading routing and all the modules have their own routing files. Everything working fine except error page redirection. If i hit `localhost:4200/error` i am able to see error page for few seconds and then automatically redirect it back to home page again.

**App-routing**

```
const routes: Routes = [
{
path: '',
redirectTo: 'home',
pathMatch: 'full',
canActivate: [AuthGuardService]
},
{
path: 'home',
loadChildren: () => import('../home/home.module').then((m) => m.HomeModule),
canActivate: [AuthGuardService],
},
{
path: 'dashboard',
loadChildren: () => import('../another/another.module').then((m) => m.AnotherModule),
canActivate: [AuthGuardService],
},
{ path: '**', redirectTo: '/error' } ];

export const Routing: ModuleWithProviders = RouterModule.forRoot(routes);
```

**Error Module**: Normal routing enabled instead of lazy loading

```
const routes: Routes = [{ path: 'error', component: ErrorComponent }];

export const ErrorRoutingModule: ModuleWithProviders = RouterModule.forRoot(routes);
```

Both modules imported to app module as usual :

```
imports:[
  .........
  ErrorModule,
   Routing
 ]
```

I am using angular 8. Any help would be really helpful.

**UPDATE:**
Found the issue, actually after successful login i am redirecting the user to home page from my service .

```
this.service.login().subscribe(response=> { if(response.valid){this.router.navigate['/home'];}
```

Need help to resolve this issue. So maybe it's a valid user but typed a wrong url in that case it should go back to `error` page. This login service is getting called from my `app-component`.

Comment: You would not route back to any other page except if you have explicitly written a code in your error component to route after few seconds... Can you add your error component code for more clear picture.

Comment: Don't have anything on my error component. just blank `constructor` function and the html page has some static content

Comment: I think am reading it wrong... You want to redirect or is it happening and you want to stop it?

Comment: It's happening but it's not staying on that page. First it's redirect and able to see the content but after few seconds it's redirect back to home page automatically .

Comment: So you mean that you first land to error page, but then automatically get redirected to home page which you don't want to happen?... Correct me if my understanding is wrong.

Comment: @pavankumar, correct. Am i missing something in my code?

Comment: Looking at your update as I told earlier you have written a logic to route to home... Ok time to fix it... Do something like if login is valid and if current url is `error` or per say current url is not empty, stay in same page else redirect to `home`

Comment: Yes, i got the logic and i can handle it with some JS code but is there any built in angular mechanism available which i can use to resolve it?

Comment: No magic available here we have to write that for ourselves... Sorry.

Answer (score -1):

Try to use this example:

```
{ path: '404', component: ErrorComponent },
{ path: '**', redirectTo: '/404' },
```

> Error component ts.

```
export class ErrorComponent implements OnInit {
  
  public msToRelocate: number = 5000;

  constructor(private router: Router) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    Observable.of(true).pipe(
    delay(msToRelocate),
    tap(() => {
        this.goToHomePage();
      }),
    );
  }

  public goToHomePage() {
    this.router.navigate(['']);
  }

}
```

Comment: Can you please explain it?